# How to make kubernetes use existing etcd cluster on bare metal ubuntu14-04?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to configure two Kubernetes cluster on bare metal ubuntu that shares the same ETCD cluster, I have no idea where to do the changes to  it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to configure the etcd instance(s) used by Kubernetes using [the `--etcd_servers` flag on the kube-apiserver component](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/server.go#L187). It also has a flag for specifying the prefix to put all of its objects under in etcd.

However, we typically recommend using a dedicated etcd instance for Kubernetes anyway so that it can't be affected by other users of the etcd cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Alex, please don't forget to configure flannel to use your existing etcd cluster, it is also relying on etcd to work.